# analyzing residuals vs. fitting a full model

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, covariance, residuals

In my field, some scientists look for relationships between a dependent variable, `y` and a covariate, `x1`, while controlling for a suite of potentially confounding covariates, `x2 - xn`. These analyses are syntheses of many environmental sampling campaigns, and because where people sample is not random, it is important to control for potentially confounding covariates.

My approach in these cases is to model `y` as a function of all potential covariates simultaneously. i.e. `y ~ x1 + x2 ... xn`. These relationships can have interactions and can take many different functional forms.

Others in my field do something different. They first fit models to `y ~ x2 ... xn`. Essentially, they model `y` as a function of everything but `x1`. They then take the residuals of this "everything but" model, and model those residuals as a function of `x1`. If `x1 -> xn` were completely independent, then this approach should converge on the same result. However, the whole reason we control for `x2 -> xn` is because of potential confounding. If there is any covariation between `x1` and other covariates (`x2 -> xn`), then in principle, this should bias the parameter estimates associated with `x1`, no?

My gut tells me this is true. The simulation below also tells me this is true. I simulate a (weak) correlation between two covariates. I then estimate the effect of `x1` using a model of `y` fit to both covariates simulataneously, or fit the residuals of a model of `y` first fit to `x2`. The parameter estimate for `x1` is considerably different. The model fit to both predictors simultaneously captures the true paraemter estimate, while the residual approach parameter estimate is nearly outside the actual distribution of parameter estimates.

Simulation:

```
output1 <- list()
output2 <- list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  x1 <- rnorm(1000)
  x2 <- x1*0.6 + rnorm(length(x1))
  #model y ~ x1 + x2
  y <- x1 *0.3 + x2 *1.2 + rnorm(length(x1))
  mod1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2) #fit y ~ x1 and x2
  mod2a <- lm(y ~ x2) #fit y ~ x2
  mod2b <- lm(residuals(mod2a) ~ x1) #estimate effect of x1 based on residuals of y ~ x2 fit.
  output1[[i]] <- coef(mod1)[2]
  output2[[i]] <- coef(mod2b)[2]
}
output1 <- unlist(output1)
output2 <- unlist(output2)

#plot
limx <- c(0, 0.5)
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
hist(output1, xlim=limx)
abline(v = 0.3, lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = 'purple')
hist(output2, xlim=limx)
abline(v = 0.3, lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = 'purple')
```

Plot:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is there a reference to argue against fitting models using a residual approach like this?
2. Is there ever a case where you would want to use a residual approach like this? I assume this might be useful if you were estimating spatial/temporal auto-correlation or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is never appropriate. If there are correlations among predictor variables, as in the example, the "residuals approach" will always bias parameter estimates. The confidence intervals of parameters estimated this way frequently do not include the true parameter value. Multiple regression will return unbiased parameter estimates, though the uncertainty in parameter estimates will increase with the degree of correlation among predictor variables. There is a paper on precisely this topic:

[Freckleton RP. 2002. On the misuse of residuals in ecology: regression of residuals vs. multiple regression. Journal of Animal Ecology. 71, 542-545.](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x)

This type of analysis is never appropriate, save for diagnostic analyses used to determine if a particular analysis meets statistical assumptions. Think standard checks for homogeneity of variance.